# Build stored procedure from EF Core developed SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I have a EF Core 8 query written in LINQ which is like below and produces the expected result. Below, the `branchIds` is `list` of `string`.

```
bool hasAccess = await _dbContext.Set<UserAssignedBranch>()
                   .Where(w => w.AgentId == agentId &&
                               branchIds.All(a => a == w.BranchId) &&
                               w.AppUserId == userId)
                   .AnyAsync();
```

Once this is executed I get the expected output.

I want to translate this to a stored procedure. So I opened the SQL Server Profiler and got the translated SQL syntax from EF Core which looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [UserAssignedBranch] AS [u]
        WHERE [u].[AgentId] = @__agentId_0 AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM OPENJSON(@__branchIds_1) WITH ([value] uniqueidentifier ''$'') AS [b]
            WHERE [b].[value] <> [u].[BranchId]) AND [u].[AppUserId] = @__userId_2) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END',N'@__agentId_0 uniqueidentifier,@__branchIds_1 nvarchar(4000),@__userId_2 uniqueidentifier',@__agentId_0='FB4426D2-F237-4F7B-FA9C-08DC2CABC414',@__branchIds_1=N'["684a6a00-0a73-4c23-f525-08dc2cabc427","5a29f7fe-3fc0-42cb-a946-e3b73e09ca13"]',@__userId_2='DBEF4707-F497-43DF-9D27-08DC2CABC51B'
```

I attempted to write the stored procedure from this, which resulted in this code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CheckBranchAccess] 
    @UserId    NVARCHAR(100),
    @AgentId   NVARCHAR(100),
    @BranchIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[]'
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result BIT;

    SELECT @Result = CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM [UserAssignedBranch] AS [u]
            WHERE [u].[AgentId] = @AgentId AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM OPENJSON(@BranchIds) WITH ([value] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER '$') AS [b]
                WHERE [b].[value] = [u].[BranchId]
            ) AND [u].[AppUserId] = @UserId
        ) THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END;

    SELECT @Result AS [Result];
END
```

This is how I call the stored procedure from C#:

```
var strbranchIds = branchIds.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToList();

List<SqlParameter> parms = new()
    {
        new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@AgentId", Value = agentId.ToString() },
        new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@UserId", Value = userId.ToString() },
        new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@BranchIds", Value = string.Join(',',strbranchIds ?? new List<string>()) }
    };

var hasClaim = await _dbContext.Set<SP_CheckBranchAccess>()
                               .FromSqlRaw("EXEC SP_CheckBranchAccess @AgentId, @UserId, @BranchIds", parms.ToArray())
                               .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: token);
```

But in this case, I'm not getting the expected result as from LINQ-to-SQL. Can anybody help me to fix this?

Comment: The EF code uses uniqueidentifier types but you switched to nvarchar.

Comment: open json doesnt support `uniqueidentifier ` i guess

Comment: Whats with Agent and User? They surely can.

Comment: "im no getting the expected result" -- Please be more specific.

Comment: For "@BranchIds" you have built wrong JSON array. You should enclose it in brackets '[]'

Comment: Also, it's not likely that `branchIds.All(a => a == w.BranchId)` produces any results. One record's `BranchId` can't be equal to *all* entries in `branchIds`. (yeah, unless there's only one entry, or all entries are equal). Another thing is that there's no need at all to use this EF trick (OPENJSON) in a stored procedure. Just use STRING_SPLIT, or a table-valued parameter and join with the table or use `IN`.

Comment: all what i want to do is compare a list of ids against the db table and if all ids are availabel in the db table, then return true, or false. how can i do that?

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's not a good idea to copy an EF-generated SQL query as-is into a stored procedure. Entity Framework really does a decent job in generating SQL —and it's getting better at it all the time— but you should *at least* check if it can be improved. Which is true here.

This trick with `OPENJSON` [was added in EF-core 8.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef8-preview-4/) to solve problems with LINQ `Contains` queries (i.e. query plan pollution and lack of scalability), but if someone would create a stored procedure from scratch, aiming at getting records based on known id values, it would be very unlikely that they would come up with this solution.

My first choice would be to use [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016). Then it's less easy to supply an incorrectly formatted parameter:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[HasAccessToAllBranches]
    @userId    NVARCHAR(100),
    @agentId   NVARCHAR(100),
    @branchIds NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH vals AS
    (
        SELECT value FROM string_split(@branchIds, N',')
    )
    SELECT CONVERT(BIT, CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM vals v
        WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM [UserAssignedBranch] AS [u]
            WHERE [u].[BranchId] = v.value
            AND [u].[AppUserId] = @userId
            AND [u].[AgentId] = @agentId
        )
    ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END);
END
GO
```

Where `@ids` would be a comma-separated string of branch ids.

This query checks if there is a `UserAssignedBranch` record, having the specified `userId` and `agentId`, for each of the supplied branch ids.

Comment: what i what to solve is to return a `boolean` if all the branchids matches in the list, then true. if any branch ids does not match in the list with the records in the db table, then false. how to do it in sql?

Comment: i just need to change the `WHERE v.value = [u].[AgentId]` to `WHERE v.value = [u].[BranchId]`

Comment: can u help with this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78032740/index-not-working-with-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: will it still work if i switch `WHERE v.value = [u].[BranchId]` to `WHERE [u].[BranchId] = v.value `?

Comment: Sure, I just thought it looks more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.Set<T>.FromSqlRaw` as this intends to return and populate an entity definition from the SQL. In your case you really just want a scalar value for True/False.  Instead, try `_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` with the desired parameters, including the OUTPUT parameter for the result.  One question would be why do you want to execute this as a Stored Proc rather than just using the Linq expression?

Comment: if i write it as `LINQ` , the query has to compile and run, but if i keep it as stored proc, its already compiled right, so it will be faster as i have to check permissions to every http request against the db. i just want to check if the provided list of Ids are available in the db table, if all matches then return true, if atleast one doesnt not match return false. how to do it using sql stored proc?

Comment: Permissions to execute by the DbContext would be performed whether running a Linq query or a Stored Proc call. As for "faster", just be sure you aren't thinking about a solution that is looking for a problem. The whole point of using an ORM like EF is to enable querying against a database without worrying about safely and efficiently writing and executing SQL. EF typically generates safe and efficient SQL so long as it is configured correctly.