# Index not working with SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have table in SQL Server which looks like the DDL below.

And I have a stored procedure which compares a list of comma separated Ids against this table and return `true` if all if all Ids passed in matches with the table, else false. The stored proc is below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HasAccessToAllBranches]
    @userId    uniqueidentifier,
    @agentId   uniqueidentifier,
    @branchIds NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH vals AS
    (
        SELECT value FROM string_split(@branchIds, N',')
    )
    SELECT CONVERT(BIT, CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM vals v
        WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM [UserAssignedBranch] AS [u]
            WHERE [u].[AgentId] = @agentId AND
                  (v.value = [u].[BranchId] AND [u].[AppUserId] = @userId)
        )
    ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END);
END
```

So as you can see, I am having the `WEHRE` clause for the `AgentId` and composit unique index `BranchId` and `AppUserId`.

But when I execute the stored proc, I don't see the index being applied at all. Below is the actual execution plan from SSMS

[image]

The final `SELECT` on the left has a yellow icon which also has a warning that I couldn't fix. I don't know if that's the reason the index is not being applied.

[image]

Query plane can be found in the link: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyYzirX3a

here is the DDL for the table and index

```
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserAssignedBranch]    Script Date: 2/21/2024 4:07:55 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserAssignedBranch](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AppUserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AgentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [BranchId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserAssignedBranch] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserAssignedBranch] ADD  DEFAULT ('0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00') FOR [CreatedOn]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserAssignedBranch] ADD  DEFAULT ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') FOR [BranchId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserAssignedBranch]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserAssignedBranch_Agent_AgentId] FOREIGN KEY([AgentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Agent] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserAssignedBranch] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserAssignedBranch_Agent_AgentId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserAssignedBranch]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserAssignedBranch_AspNetUsers_AppUserId] FOREIGN KEY([AppUserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserAssignedBranch] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserAssignedBranch_AspNetUsers_AppUserId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserAssignedBranch]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserAssignedBranch_Branch_BranchId] FOREIGN KEY([BranchId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Branch] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserAssignedBranch] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserAssignedBranch_Branch_BranchId]
GO
```

Comment: Images of names of indexes tell us *nothing*; it's like showing an image of some tables called `Customer`, `Stock` and `CustomerOrder` and expecting users on the internet to know all the columns those tables contain. Instead provide the definitions of the tables and indexes. For the plan use [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: here is the plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyYzirX3a also i have updated it in the question

Comment: Is your procedure written by EF Core?

Comment: @siggemannen, no, i got help from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78008290/5458741

Comment: So, you mean "no" as in "yes". Your branch table seem to have very few rows, is this query really a problem?

Comment: yes, with time, there will be more than a 1 million rows once we go production

Comment: Well, sql server won't bother with indexes for so few rows, so it's pointless to try. You could probably cast(value as uniqueidentifier) in the CTE but otherwise the best is to have a properly filled table when doing query tuning

Comment: @GertArnold, i have updated the question with DDL, please help!

Comment: I can't help more than the answer you already got.

Comment: But is there really a problem? As said by siggemannen, looking at the plan, performance can't be an issue. This seems to be a case of [premature optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/).

Comment: You forgot to include the index you're trying to use, defaults on the other hand aren't really interesting for performance (usually)

Comment: Ideally use a Table Valued Parameter instead of splitting strings. But yeah your indexes are a waste of time (as single column indexes often are), you need a multi-column one `(AgentId, AppUserId, BranchId)`

Comment: I hope people will reconsider their downvotes. Granted, the first draft of the question was too minimal (@thanzeel I hope you'll keep that in mind next time), but hey, someone's looking at query plans, that alone is worth a vote :).

Comment: @GertArnold, suer, i will. thanks for all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your index names indicate the relevant columns, you have three non-clustered indexes

- AgentID
- BranchID and AppUserID
- UserProfileID

When running your query, you are looking up rows based on 3 columns

- [u].[AgentId]
- [u].[BranchId]
- [u].[AppUserId]

As you have no single index (other than the clustered index) that covers all three columns, the query would need to use at least 2 indexes, then match the results, to get the answer using those indexes. Instead of doing multiple lookups and matching results, it just uses the clustered index.

If you change your index `IX_UserAssignedBranch_BranchID_AppUserID` to also include the column `AgentID`, then the index should be used (as the index covers all relevant columns).

More broadly, I would strongly recommend [Brent Ozar's 'How to think like the SQL Server Engine'](https://www.brentozar.com/training/think-like-sql-server-engine/). It takes a few hours, but is the best explanation I have seen for people who need to understand indexes. You can also just go straight to the [YouTube version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMw2knRuIlE).

Comment: Kudos for referring to this excellent video!

Comment: Thanks for the kudos @Gert and I highly recommend the video. A few years ago I thought I was decent at indexing etc (and I was better than others at my company) but that video caused an evolutionary improvement to my understanding and corresponding abilities.

Comment: Similar to me. This guy makes me realize how much I *don't* know, which is a good place to be.